# Автозаполнение БД ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, mvc

Такая ситуация: в приложении есть база с пользователями: админ, модер и юзер, допустим. Хотелось бы сделать так, чтобы при старте приложения таблица с пользователями заполнялась нужными значениями, но не представляю, как лучше сделать: либо настраивать каким-то образом сида, либо подключить скрипт SQL, чтобы выполнялся после запуска и заполнял...
Подскажите, пожалуйста, как рациональней поступить и как лучше осуществить этот вариант.

Comment: Что сейчас используется в приложении для работы с БД? Есть ли EF и если есть, какой подход к построению БД(code-first, db-first)?

Comment: @AlexKrass, а, да, локальная MySQL, EF, база создаётся кодом

Comment: В EF можно использовать механизм миграций с выполнением произвольного кода или заготовленных инструкций. Можно там указывать скрипт для выполнения, если каждый раз то внутри Configuration класса. Если единожды, можно внутри миграции после AddMigration. Хотя с миграциями надо работать осторожно и они могут показаться сложными, но попробуйте этот вариант. Так же из миграций часто можно сгенерировать скрипт SQL и потом просто выполнить его. Однако, если не уверены в себе, не используйте этот вариант и просто в конструкторе EF подгрузите и выполните SQL.

Comment: @AlexKrass, хорошо, спасибо. попробую)